# MVC Partial View Validation Message not showing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have this AjaxForm in my partial view:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateStarter", "Player", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OwnerID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Species)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Gender)
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nickname)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Nickname)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Nickname,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Choose my pokemon">
}
```

In my controller post action i verify whether or not the model is valid. If it is not i return the partial view. If the model is not valid, the partial view is returned, but the validation message is not shown. Am I missing something?
This is my action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateStarter(PokemonViewModel pokemonViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Pokemon pokemonEntity = PokemonMapper.GetPokemonEntity(pokemonViewModel);
                _userService.AddStarterPokemonToPlayer(pokemonViewModel.OwnerID, pokemonEntity);
                return RedirectToAction("PlayerProfile");
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("_CreateStarter", pokemonViewModel);
            }

        }
```

And this is my model:

```
public class PokemonViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Species { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public int OwnerID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Yes you are missing to post your code along with your question; especially, the part in your controller wherein you return the partial with validation messages and also the part where you get the partial on the client side and how you use it.

Comment: You do not do anything with the partial view you return (i.e. update the DOM). And your `return RedirectToAction("PlayerProfile");` is pointless - ajax calls NEVER redirect. Stop using ajax and make a normal submit (the whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page, and that is not what you want to do - all you doing is degrading performance)

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with partial views and ajax is not straight forward but it is not hard either. You need to do a few things:

1. Create a container (`<div>`) in your main page wherein you house you
   partial view.
2. In `Ajax.BeginForm`, specify what to do in:

   1. InsertionMode
   2. UpdateTargetId
   3. OnFailure
   4. OnBegin
3. In your controller you cannot simply return the view if the model is not valid, because that will send an `HTTP 200 OK` status indicating the request succeeded. You need to inform the client that something is not right.

**Step 1 and Step 2**

Imagine you have a main page and within that you will need to create a container for your partial and put your partial there. Also note the `OnXxx` function handlers.

```
<html>
    <!-- Your main page -->
    <div id="your-partial-form-id-here>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm( /* other arguments */
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnBegin = "DoBeforeUpdatingPage",
            OnFailure = "DoWhenThereIsAnIssue",
            OnSuccess = "DoOnSuccess",
            UpdateTargetId = "id-of-html-element-to-update-on-success",
        }))
    {
        //...code
    }
    </div>
</html>
```

All the `OnXxx` handlers are javascript method names which will handle each scenario. Here is what you may do in each:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DoBeforeUpdatingPage() {
        // Maybe nothing or maybe form validation
    }

    function DoWhenThereIsAnIssue(responseFromServer) {
        // In your case the responseFromServer is the partial view
        // so you just need to inject the html into the container 
        // you have created earlier.
        $('your-partial-form-id-here').html(responseFromServer);

        // Also since there was an issue, you may want to clear 
        // the thing which is updated when it is success
        $('#id-of-html-element-to-update-on-success').empty();
    }

    function DoOnSuccess(responseFromServer) { // whatever... }
</script>
```

**Step 3**

Return `BadRequest` to the client so the javascript `OnFailure` handler is invoked; in our case the `DoWhenThereIsAnIssue` will be invoked.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return PartialView("_NameOfPartial", model);
    }
}
```